# Argument in message expression is an uninitialized value unsigned long long to NS numbers

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

analyze is generating warning in subj.
Any suggestion?

```
const char *cString = [query UTF8String]; 
unsigned long long affectedRows;

if (self.sqlPut != NULL) { 
    mysql_query(self.sqlPut,cString); 
    affectedRows = mysql_affected_rows(self.sqlPut);
    if (affectedRows == 0) NSLog(@"MYSQL: Query: %@ was failed  with error:%s\n and error number:%d",query,mysql_error(self.sqlPut),mysql_errno(self.sqlPut));
}
else {
    [self mysqlConnect];
    if (sqlPut != NULL) {
        mysql_query(self.sqlPut,cString);
        affectedRows = mysql_affected_rows(self.sqlPut);
        if (affectedRows == 0) NSLog(@"MYSQL: Query: %@ was failed  with error:%s\n and error number:%d",query,mysql_error(self.sqlPut),mysql_errno(self.sqlPut));
    }
}
NSNumber *affectedRowsNumber = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedLongLong:affectedRows] autorelease];
return affectedRowsNumber;
```

Comment: If not using Xcode 4 with LLVM compiler, try switching to that. It has greatly improved warning messages that you would probably find useful

Comment: i'm on llvm :) GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0

Answer (score 11):

An easy fix is to change

```
unsigned long long affectedRows;
```

to

```
unsigned long long affectedRows = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If both `self.sqlPut` and `sqlPut` are `NULL`s, then the value is not initialized. Perhaps, the inner `if` needs `else`.

Comment: i don't see difference between self.sqlPut and sqlPut - i don't hide instance variables in this method

Comment: let me put it differently, then — if this variable is still NULL after `[self mysqlConnect]` ;-)